# Puzzled about Credential Details for Vertically Scaling SQL Azure using Azure Automation?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to upscale and downscale my SQL Azure instances using Azure Automation. I am using a gallery runbook called "Set-AzureSqlDatabaseEdition.ps1" which has been created by Joseph Idziorek.

The link is:  [SQL Azure vertical scale Runbook](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f/view/Discussions#content)
The parameter examples are:

```
.EXAMPLE for Set-AzureSqlDatabaseEdition  

    -SqlServerName bzb98er9bp   

    -DatabaseName myDatabase 

    -Edition Premium 

    -PerfLevel P1 

    -Credential myCredential
```

However I am confused what should go into "Crediential". Is this the SQLServer Admin Username or something else? Is it something I create in Azure Automation Assets?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an Active Directory confid setup as a Azure Automation asset, but I am unsure whether this is the recommended route?

Comment: Think I have sorted this now. Basically one need to add an Active Directory Entry, and from this, create an Automation Credential Asset which can then be used by the runbooks.

Comment: If you've figured this out, please post a proper answer (and accept it), not as a comment, so that this question can be properly resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to create a credential asset using the "SQLServer" credentials not AD, and then use the name of this for the Credential parameter value.