# Vertical Scale Azure SQL database based on Time of Day and DTU

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I have an Azure Database on P1. It is a mission-critical database. The database usually uses around 0.5% to 5% DTU at P1 level. It occasionally (once every couple of days) gets to 99.8% DTU and the requests time-out. I get an email alert from Azure at 80% DTU, so I can log to the portal and Scale-up to P2 or P4. I found a [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f) to scale the Database, but I did not understand how I can tie it to DTU level. Can you point me to some resources on how to Vertically scale Up (and Down) based on the DTU usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for you would be to create an alert, that would launch a webhook that would scale the database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-insights-alerts-portal#sql-database-alert-values-and-thresholds
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks

and\or if you know the time, just scale database with a runbook with a schedule
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-schedules

Comment: I was puzzled about the credentials part in there. You have to enter the SQL server credentials. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650319/puzzled-about-credential-details-for-vertically-scaling-sql-azure-using-azure-au/31652625#31652625